# how to git clone with specific revision and depth=1

Tags: android, git, repo

I saw a following line in a manifest file in .repo.
How can I do the same with the git command in manifest.xml?
I'd like to know how to run 'git clone' with specific revision and depth=1.

```
<project clone-depth="1" groups="pdk-cw-fs,pdk-fs" name="repository name" path="repository path" revision="SHA1"/>
```

Comment: What does `pdk-cw-fs` mean in the `groups` definition?

Answer (score 3):

If `revision` is a branch(`refs/heads/xxx`) or a tag(`refs/tags/xxx`),

```
git clone $remote -b $revision --depth=1 --single-branch
#or
git fetch $remote $revision --depth=1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

If `revision` is a specific commit or a ref under other namepaces, not `refs/tags/` or `refs/heads/`,

```
git fetch $remote $revision --depth=1 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Note that when `revision` is a specific commit at which no ref is pointing, `git fetch` would fail due to `error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object`. The variables in `git config` or the hosting service config allow to fetch an unadvertised object:

```
uploadpack.allowTipSHA1InWant
uploadpack.allowReachableSHA1InWant
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. 
I used https://github.com/hyde1004/test1.git as a sample repository. When I run 
`git fetch https://github.com/hyde1004/test1.git 6e82b0b --depth=1`
it displayed 
"fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

And when I run 
`git init && git fetch https://github.com/hyde1004/test1.git 6e82b0b --depth=1` 
it displayed 
`fatal: Couldn't find remote ref 6e82b0b`

Comment: @user3381542 Then the remote repository does not allow to fetch a single commit without a ref. Do you have any project that's hosted in Gerrit?

Comment: Finally I could fetch a repository after updating git from 1.9.1 to 2.15.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.